# What is the exact data type for inserting d/m/y h:s?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-8.4

I'm using Postgres and I have a sample form date time and format like this: `d/m/y h:s`

What is the data type for this datetime? I tried using timestamps without time zone and I received error:

> Datetime field overflow: 7 ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "30/08/2017 23:45"

How do I resolve this?

Comment: That does not sound like a Postgres error message. What is the output of `select version()`? Also: what is the **exact** statement that you are using? (**[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on some implicit conversion between a string and a timestamp is a dodgy practice. Instead, you should explicitly convert it to a timestamp with the format you have. E.g.:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('30/08/2017 23:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

Comment: I'am get undefined function `to_timestamp()`

Comment: @Aslam what postgres version are you using?

Comment: version `v1.10.5` Postgres `8.4`